# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre range y xrange en python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Veo que producen el mismo resultado, ¿la diferencia esta en la rapidez? ¿Por qué hay 2 funciones para lo mismo ?

```
> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> xrange(5)
xrange(5)
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print i
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>> for i in xrange(5):
...     print i 
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: ¿No buscaste por aquí?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Si, [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) y [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) producen el mismo resultado pero de diferente forma.

### Las bases

Como ya habrás podido adivinar la función `range` retorna una lista:

```
>>> type(range(10))
list
```

La función range ocupará la cantidad de memoria de acuerdo al tamaño del rango que le pases como parámetro.

Por otro lado la función `xrange` retorna su propio tipo de dato, el [xrange-type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#xrange-type):

```
>>> type(xrange(10))
xrange
```

Pues no hay mucha ciencia detrás del `xrange`, de hecho no tiene ninguna diferencia con respecto a `range` en cuanto al desempeño, la ventaja es que `xrange` siempre ocupará la misma cantidad de memoria (RAM) sin importar el tamaño del rango:

> The xrange type is an immutable sequence which is commonly used for looping. The advantage of the xrange type is that an xrange object will always take the same amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents. There are no consistent performance advantages.

En resumen, el objetivo final de ambas funciones es retornar listas pero podríamos decir que `xrange` lo hace a demanda por su naturaleza "floja" o "lazy".

### Iteradores

En ambos casos se tiene soporte para el protocolo de iteración ya que los dos cuentan con el método [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__):

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> r
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> r.__iter__
<method-wrapper '__iter__' of list object at 0xb603fdcc>

>>> xr = xrange(10)
>>> xr
xrange(10)
>>> xr.__iter__
<method-wrapper '__iter__' of xrange object at 0xb600e4d0>
```

Por lo que los siguientes casos son equivalentes:

```
>>> for item in r:
...     print item
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> for item in r.__iter__():
...     print item
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Lo mismo alpica para `xr`. La gran diferencia es que al iterar sobre `r` lo estás haciendo sobre una lista que ya ha sido previamente evaluada (y cargada en memoria) y al iterar sobre `xr` lo estás haciendo sobre una lista "floja" que te va pasando los valores mientras los vayas necesitando (cargando en memoria uno a la vez).

Ahora esto puede no tener mucho sentido con un rango de 10 enteros, pero inténtalo con algunos millones y notarás la diferencia en tu memoria RAM.

### Generadores

Se que esto no es parte de la pregunta inicial pero me pareció pertinente añadirlo a la respuesta ya que los generadores son objetos que finalmente implementan el protocolo de iteración.

Son parecidos a las listas de comprensión pero se crean usando paréntesis en vez de corchetes.

Ejemplos:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [x**2 for x in lista]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>> (x**2 for x in lista)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb60427fc>
```

Ahora, los generadores funcionan de forma parecida al `xrange` ya que también son "flojos" y solo retornan el valor mientras lo vayas necesitando sin cargar todo en memoria mediante el uso de la expresión [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr).

### Referencias

- [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)
- [Iterator types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)
- [Generator types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types)

Comment: muchas gracias master !! Tremenda respuesta !!

Comment: Maestro César, no olvides usar el español, en vez de "performance" usemos desempeño :D

Comment: @SalahAdDin tienes razón! Las malas costumbres son las más difíciles de dejar :D

Comment: Desempeño o rendimiento :)

Answer (score 8):

La función `range` genera una lista temporal interna que es manipulada artículo por artículo, mientras que `xrange` produce una interator (define la interfaz para recorrer el agregado de elementos y acceder a ellos, de manera que el cliente no tenga que conocer los detalles y sea capaz de manejarlos de todos modos) a través del cual se puede pasar sin el gasto de lo que podría ser un objeto de lista temporal grande.

Ejemplo:

Para `x` en `range(10000)`:
Generará una lista de **10 mil elementos** y entonces recorrerá cada uno de ellos a la vez.

Para `x` en `xrange(10000)`:
Generará **10 mil enteros** uno por uno, pasando cada uno a la variable **x** a la vez.

[Referencia](http://www.linuxnix.com/python-range-vs-xrange-functions/)

Answer (score 5):

En python2, son funciones diferentes y se explica bastante bien en la [documentación de xrange](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange) sus diferencias mínimas: `xrange` genera un [objeto xrange](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#xrange-type), y `range` genera una lista. La ventaja del objeto `XRange` es que no es necesita generar todos los elementos mientras no sea necesario, lo que supone un importante ahorro de recursos. Además, en la implementación *CPython* (que es la más común de python) se puede optimizar mucho mejor y simple este tipo de bucles.

Con Python3 deja de haber dos funciones unificándose en una única función `range` que sería equivalente a la función `xrange` de python2. Para obtener una lista es necesario invocar el constructor de listas (eg: `list(range(1000))`)