# ¿Cómo generar lista de enteros entre dos límites en vez de crearla manualmente?

Tags: python, lista, variables

Estoy creando un programa en el que uso listas que almacenan rangos de enteros consecutivos:

[image]

Ahora mismo creo la lista manualmente, pero me pregunto si existe alguna forma simple de generar la lista de enteros desde un número hasta otro sin tener que hacerlo manualmente. Por ejemplo, para generar una lista que empiece en 26 y termine en 69, es decir: `[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ..., 69]`.

Comment: Usa [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range), por ejemplo para crea una lista de enteros entre 26 y 69 haz `l = list(range(26, 70))`. No obstante deberías explicar que quieres conseguir, porque para clasificar según la edad no necesitas para nada la lista, basta con los condicionales.

Comment: graciass, era justo lo que quería

Comment: Isma he creado una respuesta algo más completa sobre `range` por si te interesa. También quiero darte la bienvenida a [es.so] y comentarte por si lo desconoces que para posibles futuras preguntas no pegues una imagen del código (esto dificulta la lectura, la reproducción y la búsqueda del mismo entre otras cosas). En su lugar lo copias como texto en la pregunta y luego lo seleccionas todo y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor para que quede correctamente formateado. En este caso, dado que no hay necesidad de reproducir el código, este aspecto tiene menos importancia. Un saludo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La forma más simple y eficiente de obtener una lista de enteros consecutivos o con una separación constante entre ellos es usar la función preconstruida [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#range).

Puede ser llamada de dos formas diferentes:

- `range(stop)`
- `range(start, stop,[, step])`. Dónde el parámetro `step` es opcional.

Por lo tanto `range` puede recibir tres parámetros posicionales, que deben ser enteros (tanto positivos como negativos):

- **start (inicio)**: indica el valor inicial del rango (se incluye en él, es el primer elemento), si no se especifica es 0 por defecto.
- **stop (final)**: indica el valor final del rango (no se incluye en él, el último elemento será por tanto `stop - 1`).
- **step (paso)**: distancia (número de enteros) que hay entre dos elementos consecutivos generados.

Retorna una secuencia inmutable sobre la que se puede iterar y que tiene como gran ventaja que se limita a preservar un determinado estado y solo almacena los tres parámetros en memoria y no todos sus elementos. Es decir, no genera cada elemento hasta que no es necesario, economizando memoria RAM por tanto.

Si quieres obtener una lista basta con pasárselo como argumento al constructor de `list`. Algunos ejemplos:

```
>>> list(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> list(range(3, 8))
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

>>> list(range(2, 11, 2))
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

>>> list(range(-3, 11, 2))
[-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

>>> list(range(0, -10, -2))
[0, -2, -4, -6, -8]
```

No obstante, uno de sus usos principales es formando parte de los ciclos `for`:

```
>>> for _ in range(5):
        print("Hola StackOverflow")

Hola StackOverflow
Hola StackOverflow
Hola StackOverflow
Hola StackOverflow
Hola StackOverflow

>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] += 3

>>> sum(n for n in range(1, 22, 2))  # Suma de los números impares hasta el 21.
70
```

Por lo tanto, para tu ejemplo basta con que hagas algo como:

```
lista = list(range(26, 70))
```

> **Nota:** `range` en Python 2.x retorna una lista directamente, siendo `xrange` el equivalente al `range` de Python 3. Ver la siguiente pregunta y sus respuestas para más información: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre range y xrange en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4533/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-range-y-xrange-en-python)

Answer (score 0):

Hazlo con un ciclo, que vaya desde el numero que deseas que inicie hasta el 69.
Inicio = 7
Fin 69
While <70
   Joven.apped(inicio)
   Inicio =inicio+1