# ¿Cómo puedo usar la sentencia if usando un rango de números en Python?

Tags: python

Quiero usar la sentencia if en un mini programa que estoy usando como práctica, pero no encuentro la manera de usar un rango de números como condición.
Así sería de forma escrita: 
if variable está entre 5-10
   print(Correcto)
¿Cuál vendría siendo el operador "Entre"?

Answer (score 7):

Como tal no existe un operador `entre`, aunque si que puedes usar los operadores de comparación `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` ("menor que", "menor o igual que", "mayor que", "mayor o igual que" respectivamente) para definir un condicional que valide si un número está dentro de un intervalo dado:

```
if 5 <= n <= 10: # incluye 5 y 10,intervalo cerrado
```

ó:

```
if 5 < n < 10: # no incluye 5 y 10, intervalo abierto
```

Cuando se dice que Python pretende ser legible para humanos, no es por nada. En tu caso también podrías usar el operador de pertenencia `in`/`not in` y `range`:

```
n = 6 

if n in range(5, 11): # si n está en el rango 5 - 10*
    print("Correcto")
else:
    print("Incorrecto")
```

con `range(5, 11)` tanto 5 como 10 se incluyen, si 5 y 10 no son valores válidos usa `range(6, 10)`. *El valor final pasado a [`range`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135622/15089) no se incluye en el mismo.

La diferencia entre la primera posibilidad y ésta última es que con `range` validas que `n` sea estrictamente 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ó 10 mientras que de la forma anterior `n` puede ser cualquier valor entre ellos, incluidos valores decimales:

```
n = 7.5

if 5 <= n <= 10:
    print("Si")
else:
    print("No")

if n in range(5, 11):
    print("Si")
else:
    print("No")
```

Usar `range` es menos eficiente pero puede ser útil en ciertas circunstancias.

El operador de pertenencia te permite comprobar si cualquier valor o variable (un objeto cualquiera) está presente en una secuencia dada:

```
c = "ack"
if c in "StackOverflow":
    print("Si")

n = 5
if n in (1, 5, 7, 9):
    print("Si")

s = (5, 7)
if s in ((1, 6), (5, 7), (9)):
    print("Si")
```