# Funcion de numeros aleatorios

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Tengo el siguiente enunciado:

> Diseñar una función llamada apuesta que genere una apuesta aleatoria de Euromillón. La apuesta está formada por la combinación de 5 números + 2 números estrella.
>   5 números aleatorios del 1 al 50, "apuesta" 2 números aleatorios del 1 al 12, "estrellas"
>   Los números no pueden repetirse.
>   La función no recibe parámetros de entrada y devuelve dos listas, una de apuestas y otra de estrellas. Las listas deben estar ordenadas de menor a mayor.

Yo he puesto lo siguiente y me da error y no sé que podría tener mal:

```
def apuesta_euromillon (a, e):
    a = int(random.randint (1,50))
    e = int (random.randint (1,12))

    print (random.randint)

    return apuesta_euromillon
```

al llamarla mediante:

```
apuesta_euromillon (a, e)
```

tengo el error:

> NameError: name 'e' is not defined

Lo que no entiendo es como puedo identificar que sean 5 números para la primera variable y 2 números para la segunda variable.

### Edición

Intentando implementar lo expuesto en la respuesta de @FJSevilla, en este momento lo tengo así:

```
import random
def apuesta_euromillon ():
    apuestas = random.sample(range(1, 51), k=5)
    estrellas = random.sample(range(1, 13), k=2)
    apuestas.sort()
    print (apuesta_euromillon ())

    return  apuesta_euromillon ()

apuesta_euromillon()
```

pero tengo el error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: ¿Que error te muestra exactamente?

Comment: Este es el error que me muestras: NameError: name 'e' is not defined

Comment: ¿Ejecutas  la función así `resultado = apuesta_euromillon (a, e)`?

Comment: Si se podría ejecutar así. Otra opción que solemos utilizar es: ```apuesta_euromillon (a, e)````

Comment: Lo que no entinedo es como puedo identificar que sean 5 números para la priemra variable y 2 números para la segunda variable

Answer (score 2):

El error es simplemente por llamar a la función mediante `apuesta_euromillon (a, e)` sin haber definido las variables `a` y `e` antes. Pero realmente es irrelevante.

Vamos por partes:

- El enunciado dice textualmente:

  > La función **no recibe parámetros** de entrada

  pero tu haces que reciba dos, `a` y `b`, la definición debe ser:

  ```
  def apuesta_euromillon():
  ```
- Por otro lado dice:

  > **devuelve dos listas**, una de apuestas y otra de estrellas

  por lo que debería ser algo como:

  ```
  def apuesta_euromillon():
      # Lógica
      return apuesta, estrellas
  ```

  en tu caso retornas `apuesta_euromillon`, es decir, retornas una referencia a la propia función y no las dos listas que deberías generar dentro.
- La linea `a = int(random.randint (1,50))` **retorna un solo entero aleatorio** entre 1 y 50 ambos incluidos. El casting a `int` es redundante, `random.randint` siempre retorna un entero, pero más importante aún, solo retorna uno, necesitas cinco y que no 5 repitan. Igual para `e`.
  Podrías usar un ciclo que mediante `randint` generara índices válidos para una lista con los 50 números de forma aleatoria e ir obteniendo el elemento de la lista y eliminándolo, no es muy complicado:

  ```
  numeros = list(range(1, 51))
  apuestas = []

  for indice_max in range(49, 39, -1):
      indice = random.randint(0, indice_max)
      apuestas.append(numeros.pop(indice))
  ```

  Pero resulta que tenemos [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) que permite obtener `k` items elegidos de forma aleatoria (pseudoaleatoria realmente) sin repetir de una lista de elementos:

  ```
  apuesta = random.sample(range(1, 51), k=5)
  ```

  ahora bastaría con ordenar usando `list.sort`:

  ```
  apuesta.sort()
  ```

  con `estrellas` hacemos lo mismo y ya lo tenemos.

Ten en cuanta que `range` genera el rango sin incluir el parámetro final `range(1, 51)` genera los números desde el 1 (incluido) hasta el 51 (no incluido).

- [¿Cómo generar lista de enteros entre dos límites en vez de crearla manualmente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/135596/15089)

---

En tu nuevo intento:

```
def apuesta_euromillon ():
    apuestas = random.sample(range(1, 51), k=5)
    estrellas = random.sample(range(1, 13), k=2)
    apuestas.sort()
    print (apuesta_euromillon ())

    return  apuesta_euromillon ()
```

cometes un error muy parecido al comentado en el segundo punto. En este caso llamas a la fucnión desde dentro de si misma dos veces ademas, una con el `print` y otra en el `return`. Esto es la definición de [recursión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n)), pero en este caso es además infinita porque no hay ningún mecanismo que termine con la cadena de llamadas.

Python limita las llamadas recursivas a 1000 por defecto, es conservador, pero lo hace para evitar que se produzca un desbordamiento de pila (stack overflow) y el intérprete termine volando por los aires. En este caso se produciría dicho desbordamiento si no fuera por el límite, eso es lo que la excepción indica.

Lo cierto es que la llamada recursiva sobra totalmente, la función se debe limitar al retornar las dos listas, ni más ni menos, no debe imprimir nada ni hacer nada más que eso, mucho menos llamarse a si misma. Por otro lado, te falta ordenar `estrellas`:

```
import random


def apuesta_euromillon():
    apuestas = random.sample(range(1, 51), k=5)
    estrellas = random.sample(range(1, 13), k=2)
    apuestas.sort()
    estrellas.sort()
    return apuestas, estrellas
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

> ```
> In [1]: apuesta_euromillon()
> Out[1]: ([8, 16, 21, 23, 27], [4, 5])
>
> In [2]: boleto = apuesta_euromillon()
> In [3]: boleto
> Out[2]: ([3, 18, 30, 41, 48], [7, 10])
>
> In [4]: apuesta, estrellas = apuesta_euromillon()
> In [5]: apuesta
> Out[3]: [7, 13, 17, 24, 37]
>
> In [6]: estrellas
> Out[4]: [5, 8]
>
> In [7]: print(apuesta_euromillon())
>   ([5, 9, 10, 13, 15], [3, 5])
> ```

Comment: Vale genial, muchas gracias! Pero mi duda es la siguiente, con eso que me dice, al ejecutarlo no me sale lo que me debería de salir que son 5 números aleatios de apuestas, 2 números aleatorios de estrellas.

Comment: Todo ello en un mismo paréntesis, no sé si me entiende

Comment: Si si, de ese error me he dado cuenta. El tema es que al ejecutarlo no me devuelve un paréntesis con esos 7 números. Para que te hagas una idea te puedo publicar un ejemplo

Comment: ```python 
    In:
        apuesta()
    Out:
        ([5, 10, 14, 24, 26], [2, 4]) ````

Comment: No sé si me esta entiendo, en un mismo paréntesis, primeramente 5 dígitos del 1 al 50 , 2 dígitos del 1 al 12

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el enunciado dice "devuelve dos lista", no "devuelve una tupla con los 7 elementos"...  `([5, 10, 14, 24, 26], [2, 4])` es la salida  que el enunciado espera de la función... De hecho puedes desempaquetar las listas retornadas:  `apuesta, estrella = apuesta_euromillon(); print(apuesta); print(estrella)`. Puedes hacer `return tuple(apuesta + estrellas)`, pero repito, esto no es lo que pide el enunciado...

Comment: Vale vale, lo entiendo. Me da este error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Ese error me sale cuando escribo lo que me puso anteriormente de : print (apuesta_euromillon)

Comment: Uf por fin!! Ahora entiendo todo, muchas gracias por la atención de verdad!! Y el formato con lo que lo ha subido es estupendo, se entiende muy bien