# Pregunta sobre ordenar de mayor a menor y que no se repitan los valores

Tags: python

```
def apuesta():
a = random.randint(1,50)
b = random.randint(1, 50)
c = random.randint(1, 50)
d = random.randint(1, 50)
e = random.randint(1, 50)
f = random.randint(1, 12)
g = random.randint(1, 12)
return apuesta
```

Hola buenas, quería preguntar que código debería añadir para que la lista me ordene los números para  que salgan mayor a menor y no se repitan, muchas gracias. Me parece que se hace con np.unique y .sort() pero no lo consigo.

Comment: Posiblemente duplicado de [Funcion de numeros aleatorios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/340422/15089)... Creo que es la misma tarea, es más se repite el mimo error de `return apuesta`... Aplicar `numpy.unique` o cualquier cosa que elimine duplicados no sirve, si los hay te dejaría menos itens de los que necesitas...

Comment: Convierte esa función en una lista. Una vez que la tengas podrías usar la función sorted().

```lista_ordenada = sorted(lista_desordenada)
print("Lista ordenada:",lista_ordenada)```