# Programa python

Tags: python, spyder

Tengo que un implementar un programa principal que solicite al usuario la introducción de 10 valores enteros, y crear una lista con todos ellos y, finalmente, hacer uso de la función anterior para mostrar la posición del primer valor negativo. No se como hacer una programa con algún bucle para que me vaya pidiendo los valores sin necesidad de poner tanto print como hice y que los vaya añadiendo a una lista.

Mi código :

```
numero1 = int(input('Introduce el primer valor:'))

numero2 = int(input('Introduce el segundo valor:'))

numero3 = int(input('Introduce el tercer valor:'))

numero4 = int(input('Introduce el cuarto valor:'))

numero5 = int(input('Introduce el quinto valor :'))

numero6 = int(input('Introduce el sexto valor:'))

numero7 = int(input('Introduce el septimo valor :'))

numero8 = int(input('Introduce el octavo valor:'))

numero9 = int(input('Introduce el noveno valor :'))

numero10 = int(input('Introduce el décimo valor:'))

lista = [numero1,numero2,numero3,numero4,numero5,numero6,numero7,numero8,numero9,numero10]

indice = 0   

print (buscar_negativo(lista,indice))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa un ciclo `for` junto a [`range`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135622/15089):

```
lista = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    lista.append(int(input("Introduce el valor i: ")))
```

o:

```
lista  = []
nums = ("primer", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto",
        "sexto", "séptimo", "octavo", "noveno", "décimo")
for num in nums:
    lista.append(int(input(f"Introduce el {num} valor: ")))
```

Ten en cuenta que esto no valida la entrada del usuario, si se ingresa algo que no sea un entero tendrá una excepción:

```
lista  = []
nums = ("primer", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto",
        "sexto", "séptimo", "octavo", "noveno", "décimo")
for num in nums:
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(f"Introduce el {num} valor: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("No ha ingresado un entero, inténtelo de nuevo")
        else:
            lista.append(n)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver el ejercicio debes **crear una función** que convierta el input del usuario en un numero entero, esto para la cantidad que seas, una vez tienes la lista de los números enteros, debes crear una función que busque en la lista que acabas de ingresar, de manera que si encuentra un negativo, buscándolo de forma lineal, imprima la posición y salga de la función:

```
def ingresoNumeros(cantidad):
   listaEnteros = [ int(input(f"Ingrese el numero en la posicion {x}: ")) for x in range(cantidad)]
   return listaEnteros

def buscarNegativo(numeros, i):
   if (len(numeros) == 0):
      return -1
   else:
      if (numeros[i] < 0):
         print('Posicion del primer negativo',i)
      else:
         return buscarNegativo(numeros, i+1)
   return

cantidad = 10
listaNumeros = ingresoNumeros(cantidad)
buscarNegativo(listaNumeros, 0)
```

**Te dejo recursos para que entiendas el código:**

*Listas por comprensión:* https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/

*Recursividad:* https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-4/llamadas-recursivas

**Recuerda** que la mejor técnica para resolver ejercicios es usando la técnica de divide y vencerás, sino sabes como resolver el problema completo, divídelo en tareas mas pequeñas y sigue con ellas. Espero haberte ayudado.