# ¿Podrias ayudarme a entender la logica de este script Python?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Es mi primera pregunta en stackoverflow.
Tengo este script de Python... Se que esta "mal" ya que tendria que usar el indice [0] pero estoy intentando entender como se comporta el parametro [x] al analizar los elementos de la lista y lo doy a modo de ejemplo.

```
lista=["a","b", "c", "d"]
for x in range(5):
    if lista[x]>lista[x+1]:
```

Entiendo que aqui "x" actua como "inspector" y va recorriendo los elementos de la lista y comparandolos, mi duda es la siguiente... En la primera vuelta toma al elemento "a" y lo compara con el elemento "b". Ahora... En la segunda vuelta toma al elemento "b" y lo compara con el "c"?? O sigue tomando el elemento "a" y lo compara con el "c"? Tengo entendido que no, que "x" a medida que se repite el ciclo "for" avanza un lugar en el indice, por lo tanto "x" en la segunda vuelta tomaria al indice "b" comparandolo con el "c". 
Pero pregunto esto porque escribi este script de varias formas y siguo funcionando, lo que hizo que me plantee esta duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás en lo cierto en tu creencia. Vamos por partes:

- [`range(5)`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135622/15089) genera un rango de enteros desde 0 hasta 4. Es equivalente a range(0, 5), pero el parámetro `stop` de `range` (5 en este caso) no se incluye en el rango.
- `for x in range(5)` itera sobre el anterior rango y en cada iteración asigna un número generado por `range` a la variable `x`:

  > ```
  > >>> for x in range(5):
  >         print(x)
  > 0
  > 1
  > 2
  > 3
  > 4
  > ```
- `lista[x]` es un indizado, en cada iteración se obtiene un item de la lista usando el valor de `x` como índice. El primer índice de la lista es el 0, de forma que:

  > ```
  > lista[0] -> 'a'    
  > lista[1] -> 'b'    
  > lista[2] -> 'c'    
  > lista[3] -> 'd'
  > ```
- `lista[x+1]` hace lo mismo, pero suma 1 a `x`. Esto permite que en cada iteración se compare un carácter con el siguiente, "a" con "b", "b" con "c" y "c"  con "d".
- `if lista[x] > lista[x+1]:` por tanto compara si un item e mayor que el siguiente:

  > `lista[0] > lista[1]` --> `'a' > 'b'`  --> `False`
  >   `lista[1] > lista[2]` --> `'b' > 'c'`  --> `False`
  >   `lista[2] > lista[3]` --> `'c' > 'd'`  --> `False`

El código es incorrecto, porque 4 no es un índice válido para esa lista, debería ser `range(3)`. Es 3 y no 4 porque queremos comparar un elemento con el siguiente, como el último rango de la lista es el 3 (la "d"), la última comparación debe ser `lista[2] > lista[2 + 1]` ("c"-"d"), si usamos `3`, `3+1` ya es un índice inválido.

```
>>> lista=["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> for x in range(3):
        print(lista[x], lista[x+1])

a b
b c
c d
```

Lo normal es usar `len` para conocer la longitud de la lista:

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for x in range(len(lista) - 1):
    print(lista[x], lista[x + 1])
```

Por cierto, una forma más eficiente de hacer lo mismo, usando iteradores directamente, desplazando uno utilizando  `zip` para iterar a la par sobre ambos:

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

lista_desplazada = iter(lista)
next(lista_desplazada) # Consumimos el primer item, ahora el siguiente es "b"
for a, b in zip(lista, lista_desplazada):
    if a > b:
        print(f"{a} es mayor que {b}")
    else:
        print(f"{a} es menor que {b}")
```